# android kitkat Uri to absolute path/input stream

Tags: android

I have tried various methods to extract the absolute path of an image from a Uri. I have checked out google and found a snippet but that does not quite work. It returns a weird address to my file, logcat says file not found.
I would be glad if anyone could share a proper method or snippet that helps me get the actual address of the Uri/ selected Image.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried various methods to extract the absolute path of an image from a Uri

[A `Uri` is not necessarily a file](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html), and so there is not necessarily an absolute path to an image.

> I would be glad if anyone could share a proper method or snippet that helps me get the actual address of the Uri/ selected Image.

You don't. You [use `ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) to access the file contents (`openInputStream()`), get the MIME type (`getType()`), etc.

Comment: This was my code before android 4.4 came out. Now im not sure how to use content resolver here :\ 

 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

Comment: @AssassinShadow: You need to treat a `content://` `Uri` much like you treat an `http://` `Uri`. You don't get "the absolute path of an image" from an HTTP URL, because that file is inaccessible to you. Instead, you download it. Similarly, you don't get "the absolute path of an image" from a `content://` `Uri`, because that file is inaccessible to you.